# Vieta's formulas - accurate or approximate?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Apologies for the simplicity of this question, I just want to make sure that I have this absolutely right.

There are lots of questions on Vieta's formulas on Mathematics Stack Exchange already. But I got confused by this page ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Vieta's_formulas), not a Stack Exchange page), which seems to imply that the formulas offer a process of approximation rather than an accurate series of equalities. I've probably misunderstood the context. However:

Define a polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ with rational coefficients and roots (not necessarily distinct) $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$. Vieta's formulas give

$$\sum_{i=0}^nr_i=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$$
$$\prod_{i=0}^nr_i=(-1)^n\frac{a_{0}}{a_n}$$

In the case of a monic polynomial $M(x)$ with rational coefficients, we have $a_n=1$ and therefore

$$\sum_{i=0}^nr_i=-a_{n-1}$$
$$\prod_{i=0}^nr_i=(-1)^na_{0}$$

My questions are: (a) do I have this right, and (b) are these precise and 100% correct formulas rather than approximations?

ADDED DETAILS:

Say, for example, that I want to explore the sign value of $\prod_{i=0}^nr_i=(-1)^na_{0}$ in order to define properties of the roots in terms of whether $n$ is odd or even. Is that something I could legitimately do?

Comment: These are exact, but will not give you the roots directly. To get the roots, you have to solve the two equations in two variables (non-linear). A simple approximation is there when one root is much bigger than the other, hence the sum of roots is just the biggest root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas are exact. However, you must be aware that the roots $r_i$ are in general not real, but complex numbers. The subset of real roots may even be empty.

The reason is that if you have the $n$ roots $r_i$ (some of them possibly multiple roots) of your polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n$, then
$$P(x) = a_n\prod_{i=1}^n (x-r_i)$$
Multiplying shows that $a_{n-1} = -a_n\sum_{i=1}^nr_i$ and $a_0 = a_n(-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^n r_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Vieta's formulas are *exact* formulas that are useful in calculating approximate values of roots in cases when one root is much smaller than the other.

Comment: Much smaller or much bigger !

Comment: Thanks for these answers, but I'm still a bit confused. I have added an example of the kind of question I might want to use the formulas for to the original posting. Essentially, the question is, are the formulas 100% accurate in terms of exploring the *properties* of roots and coefficients?